# Zariski dense subgroups and conjugates

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, algebraic-groups, geometric-group-theory, linear-groups

Let $H \leq \mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ be a finitely generated subgroup which is not Zariski dense, and let $g \in \mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$. Must there be some $a \in \mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\langle H,aga^{-1}\rangle$ is not Zariski dense?

Comment: No. If $H$ is the Heisenberg group over $\mathbf{Z}$ (the upper unipotent matrices with integral entries) and $g\in\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbf{R}$ and not $\mathbf{Q}$, it is easy to show that for every $a\in\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Q})$, the group $\langle H,aga^{-1}\rangle$ is Zariski-dense. Hint: classify $\mathbf{Q}$-defined Zariski closed subgroups containing the upper unipotent subgroup.

Comment: @YCor What if we replace "Zariski dense" by "profinite closure of infinite index"? Is the profinite closure of your example of finite index?

Comment: In $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$, Zariski dense is equivalent to having profinite closure of finite index, as I told you in a comment yesterday.

Comment: The group $<H,aga^{-1}> $  of YCor actually has finite index in $SL_3({\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: I am assuming that $a\in SL_3({\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: @YCor Is Venkataramana right? Does the index become finite for every $a \in \mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Comment: @Pablo I think so, but it's harder. Isn't it due to Hee Oh? I'm not sure of the reference but I learnt it from Misha Kapovich on MO.

Comment: It is a result of Jacques Tits (an old paper in Comptes Rendus). Hee Oh's result is about any Zariski dense discrete subgroup which intersects the upper triangular unipotents in a finite index subgroup.

Comment: @YCor: a small correction to your construction; you must assume that $g$ has no rational eigenvalues, and is diagonalisable over over $\mathbb R$; otherwise, you might end up in the integer points of a proper parabolic subgroup

Comment: @Venkataramana: yes, indeed I want no rational eigenvalue at all.